# Sort custom post type by most current date picker

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, sort, date, events

I'm trying to sort custom post type made with ACF plugin by most current date. Ideally future most current post should be first. Currently, I'm sorting by date, which gives me the earliest post as the first post.

Here is my code.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'             => 'events', 
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'meta_key'              => get_sub_field( 'date_start' ),
    'orderby'               => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'                 => 'ASC'
) );
```

Here is the screenshot of my website to make things clear. 
[image]

I have tried this post to no avail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951370/sort-wp-query-by-acf-datepicker

It seams that my `meta_query` is not properly setup. 
This is the `meta_query` that I tried.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => get_sub_field( 'date_start' ),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => current_time('Ymd'),
        )
),
```

note: for some reason I have to do `get_sub_field('date_start')` plain `'date_start'` doesn't return any results.

Comment: Is `date_start` a sub-field of a repeater or group field? Also, `get_sub_field()` and `get_field()` return the value for the current post. It doesn't make any sense to use it as the key.

Comment: `date_start` belongs to a group. This totally make sense, but for some odd reason I can't get any result without using `get_sub_field()`.

Comment: If you're getting a result with `get_sub_field()`, it's almost certainly incorrect, and by coincidence. If `date_start` is the sub field of a group, then the meta key will not be `date_start`, it will be prefixed with the group's key.

Comment: Thanks, that actually make perfect sense.

Comment: @Jacob, thanks for your input, it did the trick. Learn something everyday

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to [Jacob Peattie](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/39152/jacob-peattie) and his helpful comments I was able to resolve this issue.

`meta_key` was part of the group, but it wasnt prefixed by a group key. So, something like this totally works for me: `group_field_sub_field`. So changing that in both arrays did the trick.